# parse url and title from string of multiple href tags in coldfusion

Tags: regex, parsing, coldfusion

i need to parse the url and title from multiple href tags in a string regex...
i need to get each url and title into a variable
eg.

```
<DT><A HREF="http://www.partyboatnj.com/" ADD_DATE="1210713679" LAST_VISIT="1225055180"     LAST_MODIFIED="1210713679">NJ Party Boat - Sea Devil of Point Pleasant Beach, NJ</A> 
<DT><A     HREF="http://www.test.com/" ADD_DATE="1210713679" LAST_VISIT="1225055180"     LAST_MODIFIED="1210713679">test parse</A> 
 <DT><A HREF="http://www.google.com/"     ADD_DATE="1210713679" LAST_VISIT="1225055180" LAST_MODIFIED="1210713679">google</A>
```

Comment: i need to parse the urls and titles to get it in a structure soc loop this ex above and return results like this.
google.com google
bing.com bing

etc...

Comment: I would recommend editing your question to explain what it is that you're trying to do - what's a "soc loop"?

Comment: might wanna search "parse HTML"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if I understand correctly, I would do something like this:

```
<cffunction name="reMatchGroups" access="public" returntype="array" output="false">
    <cfargument name="text" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="pattern" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="scope" type="string" required="false" default="all" />

    <cfscript>
         l = {};
         l.results = [];

         l.pattern = createObject("java", "java.util.regex.Pattern").compile(javacast("string", arguments.pattern));
         l.matcher = l.pattern.matcher(javacast("string", arguments.text));

         while(l.matcher.find()) {
             l.groups = {};

             for(l.i = 1; l.i <= l.matcher.groupCount(); l.i++) {
                 l.groups[l.i] = l.matcher.group(javacast("int", l.i));
             }

             arrayAppend(l.results, l.groups);

             if(arguments.scope == "one")
                 break;
         }

         return l.results;
   </cfscript>      
</cffunction>
```

The above function returns groups for each regex pattern match.

You could use it like this:

```
<cfset a = reMatchGroups("<a href=""http://iamalink.com"" class=""testlink"">This is a link</a>", "href=[""']([^""|']*)[""'][^>]*>([^<]*)", "all") />
```

Which will give you an array of structs with the key-value pairs for each back reference in the regex. In this case the href and node text.

Comment: thanks for the code it works wonders!
what im really trying to achieve is to parse a HTML file exported from a browser like chrome, firefox etc. and be able to import the url's to a database. would you have a way to do that? the catch is that they have categories(folders) using <h3> tags, and i need to get the url's with each category they are in. i can clarify if necessary.
thanks

Comment: Ok for that you really need an html parser. Not sure of any in coldfusion but I'm sure a search will throw some up. I came across a simple "parser" by Ben Nadel which will store each html element in a structure. You could then look for just the h3's and write the attributes you want to the database. You may have to tweak his code though http://www.bennadel.com/blog/779-Parsing-HTML-Tag-Data-Into-A-ColdFusion-Structure.htm